# Update array of string with value from config

Tags: go

I’ve the following function which needs to provide a strings with data in two options

1. Value from config is provided ( can change only the values of `7MB` or `3MB` ) all the prefix is the same
2. If config not provided fallback to defaults which is `7MB`  and `3MB`

example

if I dont get any value from the config API the function should return **default** values, which is hard-coded in the function. like this:

```
“l_sh_dit conf_data 7MB
 l_sh_dit cert_data 3MB”
```

if im getting value from the `config` app let say 1MB (conf) and 100MB (cert) respectively the output of the function should look l

```
“l_sh_dit conf_data 1MB
 l_sh_dit cert_data 100MB”
```

The problem is that I’ve already the `defaults` value `hard-coded`, how can I update in each `element` in the array only the last value (the number 10M or all other value) , in efficient way ?

I've tried with string builder API without success as this is a bit tricky, what could be missing here?

```
func getShCfg() string{

var out []string

var b1 strings.Builder


la:= "l_sh_dit conf_data 7MB"
lb := "l_sh_dit cert_data 3MB"

cfg, ok := c.(config.Configuration)

if !ok {
    log.Errorf(“error:”, c)
    return ""
}

// here I got the data from config, else fallback to defaults 
if len(cfg.A) > 0 {

   // HERE is my problem which doesn’t works
   b1.WriteString("l_sh_dit")
   b2 := b1
   b2.WriteString("conf_data") 
   b3 := b2
   b3.WriteString(cfg.A) 

   out = append(out, b3)
} else {
    out = append(out, la)
}


// here I got the data from config, else fallback to defaults 
if len(cfg.B) > 0 {
   // HERE is my problem which doesn’t works
   b1.WriteString("l_sh_dit")
   b2 := b1
   b2.WriteString("cert_data") 
   b3 := b2
   b3.WriteString(cfg.B) 
   out = append(out, b3)

} else {
    out = append(out, lb)
}

return strings.Join(out, ";\n\r") + ";"

}
```

Comment: "HERE is my problem which doesn’t works" what error did you get?

Comment: I believe you have truncated your code, because there is variable `c` not defined, using `“` instead of `"` as double quote, appending `strings.Builder` to `out` instead of `strings.Builder.String()`. Does your code compile successfully?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by copying the builder (`b2 := b1` and `b3 := b2`)? Regardless, you should read the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder says *"Do not copy a non-zero Builder"*. But even if it was allowed why don't you just concatenate the strings? E.g. `out = append(out, "l_sh_dit cert_data " + cfg.B)`? Why make your code more complex? https://play.golang.com/p/WKMXxCXGuTt

Comment: I didn't even understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @mkopriva - thanks this helps, can you please add it as answer and i'll close the question, in addition, in case I've 5 properties which I need to handle this way do you suggest to do with the same pattern (if else for each field) or you recommended other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons your program is failing is because you are copying a non-zero [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) instance which is disallowed.

> A Builder is used to efficiently build a string using Write methods.
>   It minimizes memory copying. The zero value is ready to use. **Do not
>   copy a non-zero Builder.**

Also, and I may be wrong here, but I believe the builder is intended to provide better performance for when dealing with complex enough rules where the use of numerous individual steps to build up the string is justified. Yours is not one of those cases, however, because all you need is a single concatenation to get what you want.

```
type Cfg struct { A, B string }

func getShCfg(c Cfg) string {
    var out []string

    la := "l_sh_dit conf_data 7MB"
    lb := "l_sh_dit cert_data 3MB"

    if len(c.A) > 0 {
        out = append(out, "l_sh_dit conf_data " + c.A)
    } else {
        out = append(out, la)
    }
    if len(c.B) > 0 {
        out = append(out, "l_sh_dit cert_data "+c.B)

    } else {
        out = append(out, lb)
    }

    return strings.Join(out, ";\n\r") + ";"

}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/WKMXxCXGuTt

---

Additionally if the number of the config properties grows and you want to avoid writing too many if-elses then you can always extract that logic into a func.

```
func getCfgProp(key, val, def string) string {
    if len(val) > 0 {
        return key + " " + val
    }
    return key + " " + def
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/daXqV4-Umza